# How to import self-written python files from other paths?

Tags: python

Yes, there are lots of questions asked about this, I read all of them, but none of them helped.

So I have `db` and `registration` packages in `project` package. The structure looks like this:

- `project`

  - `db`

    - `db.py`
    - `__init__.py`
  - `registration`

    - `registration.py`
    - `__init__.py`

I want to import my `db.py` file to `registration.py` file. Tried almost everything but it is still not working.

Comment: Are you using any framework, or is this standalone code?

Comment: I'm just using mysql.connector

Answer (score 1):

Make the toplevel directory a module too

```
project/
  __init__.py       << add this
  db/
    __init__.py
    db.py
  registration/
    __init__.py
    registration.py
```

then use

```
from ..db import db
```

Comment: It's not working, I did exactly what you said.

Comment: Agreed with Nils. An uglier alternative would be adding the path full using sys.path.append(C:/blah/blah/project/db)

Comment: Please post the error messages you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with this

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/db.py')
```

Then you can now import functions if any from db.py

Answer (score 0):

You should create a setup.py in your project folder with something like :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='project',
    version='1.0.0',
    use_scm_version=True,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'': ['*.json']},
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7'
    ]
)
```

You can then install from the command line with :

```
pip install -e .
```

Finally to import db into registration it'll be :

```
from db.db import * # or whatever you want to import
```